# mysqld: Job failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, daemon

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Command: sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start

Occasionally mysqld failed to start. I don't make any changes in my.cnf or any other configuration on this laptop. One day it's ok, another I have this error.

```
syslog:
Aug 11 11:09:14 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1915.342628] type=1400 audit(1344708554.812:75): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5808 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 11 11:09:16 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1917.039784] init: mysql main process (5812) terminated with status 1
Aug 11 11:09:16 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1917.039816] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Aug 11 11:09:16 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1917.382623] init: mysql post-start process (5813) terminated with status 1
Aug 11 11:09:16 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1917.396212] type=1400 audit(1344708556.868:76): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5859 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 11 11:09:18 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1918.981751] init: mysql main process (5863) terminated with status 1
Aug 11 11:09:18 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1918.981774] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Aug 11 11:09:18 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1919.436244] init: mysql post-start process (5864) terminated with status 1
Aug 11 11:09:18 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1919.455425] type=1400 audit(1344708558.928:77): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5910 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 11 11:09:20 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1921.155101] init: mysql main process (5914) terminated with status 1
Aug 11 11:09:20 oleg-laptop kernel: [ 1921.155165] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

/var/log/mysql.err and mysql.log are empty.

Any clue?

UPD:

When starting deamon manually I have interesting output:

```
Command: sudo -u mysql mysqld
....
120811 11:28:19 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.1.3'; port: 3306
120811 11:28:19 [Note]   - **'192.168.1.3' resolves to '192.168.1.3'**;
120811 11:28:19 [Note] **Server socket created on IP: '192.168.1.3'**.
120811 11:28:19 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
120811 11:28:19 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120811 11:28:19 [ERROR] Aborting
```

But

```
Command: ifconfig
...
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          **inet addr:192.168.1.2**  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Which means mysql tries to bind to 192.168.1.3 while actual IP address is 192.168.1.2. Any ideas why that could happen? Laptop  is connected to Wi-Fi DHCP network.

Comment: Maybe related -- http://tanghus.net/2012/03/yet-another-mysql-vs-apparmor-barf/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution. No changes, so far.

Comment: Ok, here is the solution to this issue:

In my.cnf file there was a line:

    bind-address            = 192.168.1.3

After changing it to

    bind-address            = localhost

Mysql started normally. I'm pretty sure, I didn't put the IP address there manually, so it was added there by mysql itself.

Well, be careful with mysql and DHCP then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution to this issue:

In my.cnf file there was a line:

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.3
```

After changing it to

```
bind-address = localhost
```

Mysql started normally. I'm pretty sure, I didn't put the IP address there manually, so it was added there by mysql itself. Well, be careful with mysql and DHCP then.

Answer (score 0):

try any of these:

- Try to disable aparmor
- Try to re-install mysql
  Or rest of the solutions are mentioned in this url:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.1/+bug/573318

Comment: After finding this networking issue, not sure the problem is in apparmor. Don't want to reinstall now, but it maybe an option, though

Comment: have you went through all the solutions mentioned in the URL i posted?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything from there. Actually I took an idea to start mysql manually and see the output from there. Thanks!